# What invisible content to add to a div so it shows up in the page?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make a contentless div show in the page:

```
<div class="modal-border"></div>

.modal-border {
  background-color: $primary-color
  width: 5px
  height: 100%

  &:before {
    content: ' '
  }
}
```

I thought `content: ' '` would make the trick ... but the div only shows when I do something like `content: 'content'`. However, I don't want to show any content.

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Height cannot be in percent, It either takes the child height, other wise give height=100px; /or something

Comment: If an answer was found suitable please accept one, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your content, just add unicode `\00a0` which is a non-breaking space. So,

`div::before { content: "\00a0"; }` Note that it's *two* colons.

You don't need your height property and you may not need your width property. If you want to set width, you'll need to `display:inline-block;` or `block` to the `::before` property.

Make sure you specify UTF-8 in the `<head>`

`<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Answer (score 3):

It needs a defined height and a width to show up. If height is a percentage it needs a parent element with a defined height.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<br/>` break lines to the div to create space if you are looking for that. otherwise fixed height should work..

Comment: Oh, the `br` did the trick. Without having to set any height.

Comment: @alex Do NOT do this. That's a hack at best.

Comment: @Rob Is there a better solution? Without setting the height?

Comment: well thats not a hack, its a proper html tag which creates a line break. but whatever.. And moreover ive given him both the solutions in the answer if you can read clearly @Rob

Answer (score 1):

just add **&nsbp;** inside the div

like this:

```
<div class="modal-border">&nbsp;</div>
```